# Not able to import FBSDKWebDialog in the file

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I need to post on my friends wall and I am using facebook sdk 4.2 but any how not able to import even the class `FBSDKWebDialog` which is required to post on wall using its below class method

```
+ (instancetype)showWithName:(NSString *)name
                  parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                    delegate:(id<FBSDKWebDialogDelegate>)delegate;
```

I have already imported the below classes

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>
```

and I am using cocoa pods for the facebook sdk 4.2

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.2'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.2'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.2'

Help !!

Answer (score 0):

**Check** whether you have done the following things:-

> ```
> 1. Included the latest Facebook SDK
> 2. Included the AdSupport, Social, Account, Security and libsqlite3.dylib.
> 3. Added the sample code from Facebook.
> 4. Added -lsqlite3.0 -ObjC to Other Linker Flags as well
> 5. Added the app id to the plist
> 6. Added the FBUserSettingsViewResources bundle and       FacebookSDKResources.bundle to the project
> ```

Comment: I am using cocoa pods so I don't think any framework is missing !!

Comment: @DhavalH.Nena Then you must mention it your question that what procedure you are following! So that you can get answer accordingly rather than posting in comments.